# How php know what is the class name (when calling class_exists) in advance?

Tags: php, oop

I saw a code (I stripped it out for clarity) like this :

```
require_once __DIR__ . './../vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoload

if (!class_exists(RtclStore::class)):
    final class RtclStore
    {
...
    }
endif;
```

I'm wondering how php know what is RtclStore::class before class declaration in the first run? In second run of course the class is defined, but in first run there's no class so there's no ::class.
Is this has anything with composer and autoload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RtclStore::class` is just a simple string. From the PHP perspective, it's plain text.

```
var_dump(ANYTHING\YOU\WANT::class);
```

```
string(17) "ANYTHING\YOU\WANT"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sSl7d#v8.2.5)

One benefit is that IDEs and linters are able to identify them as class usages. Another one is that you get a fully-qualified name according to current namespace:

```
namespace One\Two\Three;

var_dump(FOO\BAR::class);
```

```
string(21) "One\Two\Three\FOO\BAR"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rnKWI#v8.2.5)

So it's basically a smart namespace-aware text generator :)

Aside that, [class_exists()](https://php.net/class_exists) just receives a class name as string and triggers autoloading or not depending on the value for its second argument:

```
 class_exists(string $class, bool $autoload = true): bool
```

You could just pass the generated string and everything would work the same way:

```
if (!class_exists('RtclStore')) // Or whatever the file namespace is
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why and how the code was designed in the first place.

I can think of 2 reasons:

1. The file you refers to would be included multiple times in the program. In that case, do the [class_exists()](https://www.php.net/class_exists) check will prevent PHP error in redeclaring class.
2. A version of `RtclStore` might exists within the scope of [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) in your composer.

If (2) were true, the function [class_exists()](https://www.php.net/class_exists) will trigger the attempt to autoload of `RtclStore` class. Composer will then try to find the class file and include it before doing the actual class exists check.

In both case, `RtclStore` might or might not exists before the condition check. And it makes sense to only declare `RtclStore` after check.